Cloud Function Emulator set up
Following https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/functions-emulator#functions-local-ff-install-python
$ gcloud alpha functions local deploy functions-2 --entry-point=hello_http --runtime=python312
ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.functions.local.deploy) (1, 'Docker failed to execute: failed to list container functions-2')

True, I don't have a functions-2 deployment, but I thought the whole point was for this to generate a deployment. Help?

You must create (write) a Cloud Function before you can deploy it (locally or otherwise). Deployment, in this case, refers to moving code from development into an environment in which it can be run (test|production).

Thanks, @DazWilkin. I've already done that. I invoked the command in the directory where I had the main.py and requirements.txt..
